# How to disable chunked encoding and use buffered for Jersey 1?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client, jersey-1.0

I am encountering a HTTP response status of 411 Length Required when performing a call to a 3rd party service in my application.

The problem seems to be related to `chuncked encoding`, switching it to `buffered` would solve the problem. 
There is a solution here for Jersey2: 
[Jersey Http Client replying with 411 on POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142850/jersey-http-client-replying-with-411-on-post-request)

However due to some legacy, we are using Jersey1 in our application and we can not perform a migration in the close future.

I tried to isolate the problem. Here is the minimal code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;


/**
 * Main
 */
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, null);
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

    String postURL = "https://api.napster.com/v2.2/me/library/tracks?id=tra.169783383,tra.30621111";
    WebResource webResourcePost = client.resource(postURL);
    webResourcePost.header("Content-Length", 0);
    ClientResponse response = webResourcePost.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
  }

}
```

Here is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}

mainClassName = "Main"

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey.contribs', name: 'jersey-apache-client', version: '1.19.4'
    compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19.4'
}
```

What I have tried is to add the configuration which would switch to a buffered call:

```
clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, null);
```

I quote from the documentation of the property `PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE`

> If the property is absent then chunked encoding will not be used. A value < = 0 declares that chunked encoding will be used with the default chunk size. A value > 0 declares that chunked encoding will be used with the value as the declared chunk size.

Even if I set this property I still receive the HTTP response status of 411 Length Required.

**Later edit:** My call does not leave the the local machine. When it does so I am expected to receive a 401 Unauthorized, since I will need to add a header with an auth key. Yet this is not the focus of this question, however if anyone considers is better to add details on how to obtain this, please leave a comment and I will describe more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with

You do not have to set flag `ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE`, please check [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey-client/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig.java#L113) or in your quote above.

Jersey Client by default will set the `Content-Type` as `application/json` (by nature), thus you should have passed the blank json object to get the `Content-length` correct passed in with http request.

Thus to get it work, you should `post` a blank `json` object without setting the `Content-Length` Header.

Here is the working code, where you will get `HTTP 401`

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

/**
 * Main
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    //clientConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.PROPERTY_CHUNKED_ENCODING_SIZE, null);
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));

    String postURL = "https://api.napster.com/v2.2/me/library/tracks?id=tra.169783383,tra.30621111";
    WebResource webResourcePost = client.resource(postURL);
    //webResourcePost.header("Content-Length", 0);
    ClientResponse response = webResourcePost.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, "{}");
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rishikesh Darandale, this is the solution